# Lock to Cursor no longer centers view automatically?

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, 3d-cursor

Before, checking the "Lock to Cursor" option in the "View" tab, permanently locked my 3D-view to the cursor, meaning wherever I clicked, the view would automatically center to and rotate around.
Since I updated to 2.75 though, this doesn't work anymore. Now, when I check "Lock to Cursor", all it does is use the cursor as a pivot point. The 3D-view rotates around the cursor, but it the view doesn't center to the cursor.

This makes editing pretty frustrating, since i always used to navigate the 3D-view like that. every effort to find some option in the user preferences was unsuccessful.

Comment: Same issue here. I found the former "lock to cursor" behaviour much more intuitive and I'm having a hard time getting used to it. Although I can understand that this is a personal preference. Therefore, it might be better better to be able to select between both options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was changed in [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBc5748f3cc7551c0ded385a782312bd8171818839):

> The view would jump each time, now compensate by adjusting the cursor panning.
> Less jarring and helps avoid problems when the cursor gets outside the view, see: [T40353](https://developer.blender.org/T40353)

You can now center the view on the cursor with *3D View Header > View > Align View > Center View to Cursor*, or, while *Lock to Cursor* is enabled, *3D View Header > View > Frame All* (<kbd>Home</kbd>).

[image: screenshot showing the view > frame all, view > align view > center view to cursor, and 3D view sidebar > view > view lock > lock to 3D cursor settings, each highlighted with an orange box]

In the Blender 2.7x keymap, *Center View to Cursor* is bound to <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>.

---

[There](https://developer.blender.org/T40353) are [several](https://developer.blender.org/T45301) bug [reports](https://developer.blender.org/T45313) from users who appear to have missed this functionality, so perhaps if you send a message to the [bf-funboard](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact#Requesting_Features) with an explanation why and how the old behavior was more useful than the new behavior, the developers may decide to add it back in some form.